# Autoloading nested files

Tags: php, composer-php

In my Laravel package I have some of my model traits under `/src/Models/Traits`.

The src folder is autoloaded in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Acme\\Package\\": "src"
            ......
```

Therefore any file under `src` can be used in the packages parent application by:

```
use Acme\Package\SomeHelper;
```

Is there a way to keep my traits under `/src/Models/Traits`, but have them accessible in parent applications like the following?

```
use Acme\Package\SomeTrait;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) includes this statement:

> If you need to search for a same prefix in multiple directories, you can specify them as an array

So in your example, you could specify two directories to search like this:

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { 
             "Acme\\Package\\": ["src", "src/Models/Traits"]
        }
    }
}
```

---

As an aside, in case it's not clear, `use` statements and autoloading are unrelated features. The `use` statement allows for [aliasing/importing a namespaced name](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) within a particular file, and is processed as a string replacement by the compiler without any reference to the class or trait definition. The [autoloader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is triggered at run-time when a class, interface, or trait is referenced but hasn't yet been defined. A `use` statement on its own does not trigger the autoloader.